# dependsonmethods not sequencing properly

Tags: testng

Hope some one will help me on this.
I am currently trying to write some automation tests using TestNG.

I have a ClassA with  the following methods:

```
ClassA:

    TestA1()

    @Test( dependsOnMethods = { "TestA1" })
    TestA2()  //dependsonmethod TestA1()

    TestA3()

    @Test( dependsOnMethods = { "TestA3" })
    TestA4() depends on TestA3()
```

Now  when i run testng it sequences like this :

```
TestA3() 
TestA1()
TestA4()
TestA2()
```

My testng xml looks like below ::

```
<test name="SampleTest">
    <parameter name="test.TestA1" value="TestA1" />
    <parameter name="test.TestA2" value="TestA2" />
    <parameter name="test.TestA3" value="TestA3" />
    <parameter name="test.TestA4" value="TestA4" />
  <groups>
      <run>
         <include name="@mode@" />
      </run>
  </groups>
 <classes>
     <class name="test.sampleTest" /> 
 </classes>
</test>
```

I want testng to execute something like below
Can anyone please help me out how can i achieve the order?

```
TestA1() 
TestA2()
TestA3()
TestA4()
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate test1 and test3 as @Test as well.  Make A3 depend on a2.